# Trying to update my quantity of stock by updating the a value into my database that i got out earlier by using the ID

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

need to update my SQL database with new number but I cant seem to be able  to do so. I'm using python with SQLite I'm not really any good at SQL so any help would be appreciated. I couldn't find a way to update it straight away so I thought a work around would be to get the number from the database then turn it back into a string to be enter back in. I'm sure I'm making this more difficult then it needs to be ive been stuck for a long time and really just dont know what to do now

```
def delete():
    #create a database or connect ot one
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Food_item.db')

    #create cursor
    c = conn.cursor()
    
   
    # Delete a record
    if (len(f_name_editor.get()) != None and len(l_name_editor.get()) == 0):
        print ("hello")
        c.execute("DELETE from FOOD WHERE oid= " + f_name_editor.get())
        
    elif (len(f_name_editor.get()) != None and len(l_name_editor.get()) != None):
        
        c.execute("SELECT QUANTITY FROM FOOD WHERE ADMIN_ID= "+ f_name_editor.get())
        record_id = f_name_editor.get()
        records = c.fetchone()[0]
        sub_num= l_name_editor.get()
        new_items= (records-int(sub_num))
        Removed_items =str(new_items)
        print(Removed_items)
        
        c.execute("UPDATE QUANTITY FROM FOOD  =" +Removed_items+" WHERE ADMIN_ID= "+f_name_editor.get())
```

Comment: You can use `UPDATE` SQL statement to update a record in a table.

Comment: im sorry im new to the site can you see my picture

Comment: No.  Better don't post image of code, paste the code in the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UPDATE` SQL in your code is invalid, it should be:

```py
c.execute('UPDATE FOOD SET QUANTITY = ? WHERE ADMIN_ID = ?',
          (Removed_items, f_name_editor.get()))
conn.commit()
```

Better use placeholders to avoid SQL injection and you need to call `conn.commit()` to make the update effective.

---

Note that if `l_name_editor.get()` is the amount to be deducted from `QUANTITY`, you don't need to get the current `QUANTITY`. Just use one `UPDATE` SQL as below:

```py
c.execute('UPDATE FOOD SET QUANTITY = QUANTITY - ? WHERE ADMIN_ID = ?',
          (l_name_editor.get(), f_name_editor.get()))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: thank you so much it looks so simple now but i was literally stuck on this for hours